# Integrate Skype link in Flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, skype

- How to integrate Skype link in Flex application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you have Skype installed on your computer:

```
<s:Button label="Skype Call" click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest('skype:mynumberhere'))" />
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you very much ! :) It is exactly what i have been looking for :)